# How to parse xml using vtd-xml without hardcoding attr name?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, vtd-xml

This is my sample XML file which is actually above 2gb. Using vtd-xml I have achieved this much:

**Current Code:**

https://gist.github.com/shadow-fox/21d1d4f30cbed0909f403c3ac0e1fa4d

```
public void reader() throws IOException, ParseException, NavException, XPathParseExceptionHuge, NavExceptionHuge,
            XPathEvalExceptionHuge {
        VTDGenHuge vg = new VTDGenHuge();
    if (vg.parseFile("sku_extract_main.xml",true,VTDGenHuge.MEM_MAPPED)) {
        VTDNavHuge vnh = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilotHuge aph = new AutoPilotHuge(vnh);
        aph.selectElementNS("*", "*");
        int i = 0;
        while (aph.iterate()) {
            int t = vnh.getText();
            if (t != -1) {
                System.out.println(vnh.toString(vnh.getCurrentIndex()) + "|||" + vnh.toNormalizedString(t));
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Current result:**

```
PVAL|||298374234
PVAL|||1231
PVAL|||brown
PVAL|||medium
PVAL|||7
PVAL|||solid
PVAL|||brown
```

**What I want:**

```
Sku_ID|||298374234
LotNum|||1231
COLOR|||brown
WIDTH|||medium
SIZE|||7
Pattern|||solid
Color Family|||brown
```

**Sample xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<RECORDS>
  <RECORD>
    <PROP NAME="Sku_ID">
      <PVAL>298374234</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="LotNum">
      <PVAL>1231</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="COLOR">
      <PVAL>brown</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="WIDTH">
      <PVAL>medium</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="SIZE">
      <PVAL>7</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="Pattern">
      <PVAL>solid</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="Color Family">
      <PVAL>brown</PVAL>
    </PROP>
  </RECORD>
</RECORDS>
```

And I don't want to hard code the `attr` name. I want to retrieve them as I visit them. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my edit of your code to print out attr names and values... it is xpath based...

```
public static void main(String s[]) throws Exception{
     VTDGenHuge vg = new VTDGenHuge();
        if (vg.parseFile("d:\\xml\\sku_extract_main.xml",true,VTDGenHuge.MEM_MAPPED)) {
            VTDNavHuge vnh = vg.getNav();
            AutoPilotHuge aph = new AutoPilotHuge(vnh);
            AutoPilotHuge aph2 = new AutoPilotHuge(vnh);
            aph.selectElementNS("*", "*");
            aph2.selectXPath("@*");
            int i = 0;
            while (aph.iterate()) {
                System.out.println(vnh.toString(vnh.getCurrentIndex()));
                int t = vnh.getText();
                if (t != -1) {
                    System.out.println(vnh.toString(vnh.getCurrentIndex()) + "|||" + vnh.toNormalizedString(t));
                    i++;
                }

// below is the my addition
// it basically evaluates the attribute axis
// push pop ensure that the node iteration of the outer while loop
// is consistent
// resetXPath is key here, without it, xpath will not work except for the
// first node returned by aph.iterate()
                vnh.push();

                while((i=aph2.evalXPath())!=-1){
                    System.out.println(" attr name "+vnh.toString(i));
                    System.out.println("attr val   "+vnh.toString(i+1));
                }
                aph2.resetXPath();
                vnh.pop();
            }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add comments on what is doing what ? ```vnh.toNormalizedString(t)``` this gives me the value of the attr eg. 298374234 , but within only in if scope but not in the while scope where it throws ```IndexOutOfBoundsException```. And ```vnh.toString(i+1)``` gives me the name of the attr eg. Sku_ID.

Comment: what do you mean by indexoutofBoundsException?

Comment: About the IndexOutOfBoundsException is where I try to pull the attr value i.e. vnh.toNormalizedString(t) in the while scope.

Comment: And the ```t = vnh.getText(); vnh.toNormalizedString(t)``` this is the actual value of that node.

Comment: that doesn't look like attribute at all, is that text value you are alluding to?

Comment: Is there anyway I can do one-to-one mapping ? Currently the result looks like this: ``` attr name NAME
attr val   Sku_ID
PVAL|||298374234
```, I can do ```Sku_ID 298374234```?

Comment: The reason I ask is whether I can convert this one to Java pojo or not, as the name and value comes in different scope hence not able to map it one-to-one.

Comment: I showed you how to extract attributes. How to make use of those attributes is an exercise left to you..Right?

Comment: As along as text index is not -1 you should not get index out of bound exception.

Comment: Thank you appreciate it. I have another question which I will ask in separate question regarding searching through the same xml with the attr value.